# ReaderWriterLockSlim does not solve mutliple threads writing to the file

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

when I run method DoStuff() from below class I sometimes get an exception:

```
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
```

Why can it occur? I think that ReaderWriterLockSlim should solve that potential problem?

```
public class Test
{
    private ReaderWriterLockSlim lock_ = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();
    public Test()
    {

    }

    public void DoStuff()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Task[] tasks = new Task[5];
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                tasks[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                        lock_.EnterReadLock();
                        try
                        {
                            File.AppendAllText("test.txt", "test");
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            lock_.ExitReadLock();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            Task.WaitAll(tasks);
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

The point of a reader/writer lock is to allow multiple readers and a single writer. From [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Use ReaderWriterLockSlim to protect a resource that is read by multiple threads and written to by one thread at a time.

You're doing writing using a read lock, so it's not entirely surprising that multiple threads are allowed to do the same thing - that's what it's designed for.

Change your code to use `EnterWriteLock` and `ExitWriteLock` instead. Perhaps reading some of the examples [in the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim(v=vs.110).aspx) would be helpful.